# Nodejitsu and bower install

Tags: javascript, npm, bower, nodejitsu

Did anybody try to deploy application that uses **https://github.com/bower/bower** to **Nodejitsu** hosting?

The problem is `npm pack` command which is used by nodejitsu to deploy app. It ignores all files that are starting with dot, and especially `.bowerrc` that's why I cannot run `bower install` as post deploy script..

Any suggestions? Maybe to use empty `.npmignore` file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should commit the `components` folder when creating apps. This is the recommended practice for with npm too. That way you can ensure that you only deploy exactly what you have locally. Bower will get a `shrinkwrap` command eventually, but for now this is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was always thinking that stuff that delivered by package managers is something that should be away from source control.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and (somehow) I solved it without committing the `bower_components` folder. Since Bower reached 1.0, it is possible to consume the API programatically rather than going through the command line interface. Hence, you can create a small script as below:

```
var bower = require('bower'),
    path = require('path');

bower.commands
.install([path.resolve(".")])
.on('end', function (installed) {
    console.log(installed);
});
```

On Nodejitsu it is possible to trigger commands pre and post deployment using the `script` field in your `package.json`. Thus, I can trigger my bower install on postdeployment with:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts" : {
    "predeploy": "echo This will be run before deploying the app",
    "postdeploy": "node bower_install.js",
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  }
}
```

Where `bower_install.js` is the script above.

Comment: Nodejitsu's postdeploy script runs *locally*, so using it will only install the components locally (not on the server).  You could use this technique, but you'd have to do it in your app (maybe on startup).